# Is there a way to store and select pre-configured bash commands with placeholders in Windows Terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, command-line, windows-terminal

I need to implement a command list for windows terminal which store commands to select one of pre-configured commands to enter it in command line prompt by entering/clicking on it.
Then we can complete or fill placeholders before executing.

For example:

```bash
git commit -a -m "$"
```

I have searched for it but I have not found the best solution.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "clicking it", but you could define a function or a separate script. Both accept parameters. See the bash man-page, section _Shell Function Definitions_. In your case, you could name the function i.e. `gcom` and invoke it with the commit message as parameter, for instance `gcom "first commit"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily with the placeholders bit, but you can do something similar with the `sendInput` action. For example, I have something like the following in my `actions` in the `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "command": 
    {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "git add --all\r"
    },
    "name": "add all"
},
{
    "command": 
    {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "git commit -m \"\"\u001b[D"
    },
    "name": "commit..."
},
{
    "command": 
    {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "git fetch & git pull\r"
    },
    "name": "fetch&pull"
},
{
    "command": 
    {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "git merge origin/main\r"
    },
    "name": "merge main"
},
{
    "command": 
    {
        "action": "sendInput",
        "input": "git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:\"%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%C(reset)\" --all\r"
    },
    "name": "graph"
},
```

Then you can just open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>, and fuzzy-find them in there.

(I even go a step further and [nest these all under](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-palette#nested-commands) a `git...` entry, so they're all grouped together.)

addenda:

- I'm tracking some improvements to this workflow in https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1595
- "placeholders" are tracked in:
  https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/12927